# SQL Server : analogue of Oracle package or classes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to share a few stored procedures into a single logic subset. In Oracle, I can create a "package" or class.

Is there a way do something similar in SQL Server 2012?

I don't want stay this procedures in main storage, I already have some hundreds of it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using different database schema (create your own) to logically separate your database objects (stored procedures). Packages don't exist in MS SQL.